# Laplace transform involving two functions of t

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to solve the following
$$ \int_0^{\infty} f(t)g(t)e^{rt} dt$$
Where $$g(t)=t^n$$
Letting r=-s we have the definition of

$$ \mathcal{L} [ f(t)g(t) ]$$
and am unsure how to continue.

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$? What is the integral with respect to, $dt$ or $dr$???

Comment: They are just general functions, is there not a method i can use in the general case and then apply any f or g?

Comment: Depends what you want, wikipedia lists a pretty nasty identity for what you tried to do (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

Comment: Also, if you are integrating in $dr$, $f(t),g(t)$ go outside of the integral. If you are integrating in $dt$ , you need to set $r = -s$, not $r=s$ as you suggest

Comment: Of course youre integrating with respect to $dr$. That goes without saying. Anyone who knows what a laplace transform is understands what you meant.

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: Can anything be done if we define one of the functions as i have done now?